# Is this a sensible way to examine the effects of x on y for two different groups?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, mixed-model, regression-coefficients, rstan

Let's say I have data from a number of brain regions in both teenagers and adults. I want to know if brain regions b1, b2, etc (selected based on theory) differ in their effect on a normally distributed outcome variable depending on age group. I also have data from multiple locations, which I am including as a random effect.

In LME4 notation (using brms), my model is of the form:

Y ~ log_x1:Age + log_x2:Age + (1|Institution)

I am not interested in whether teenagers and adults differ in their means for the outcome variable. I am only interested in whether or not the influence of these predictors on that outcome differ between teens and adults.

Browsing similar questions on here I see that generally interactions without main effects are a bad idea, but here, the main effect of age on the outcome variable has little relevance to the research. The only main effect that might be of interest is an estimate for each continuous predictor across age group.

Comment: How is your age variable coded? It should be 0,1 where 0=adolescents, 1=adults (or vice versa). If you code it like that, then the main effect of brain region is the effect for adolescents, and the interaction effect is the effect for adults.

Comment: @Brett  Adults are 1, but this is how brm is doing it by default. Is there a way to get brms to report all effects as age-specific, or give across-age estimates with estimates for both ages separately? Or is coding it like I have with brain:age to get just age group estimates acceptable? 

I'm fairly new to brms and never used lme4 before that. I'm a student, and I've been reading up on Gelman and Hill's classic but my mentor uses SPSS rather than R.